# Is it correct to say i-th column, in the same meaning like for 5th column?

Tags: matrices

This question is also related to English, but I decided to post thread here as it may have different usage in mathematics.

In numbers, when we say the order, we say, 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. Those **"st"** and **"nd"** changes depending on the number.

The question is what is the correct usage when I want to express the line and column in matrix. For example, i-*th* row and j-*th* column? Is is correct to use **"th"** in case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: it is correct to talk about the *i*<sup>th</sup> column or the *j*<sup>th</sup> row. It would be strange and *incorrect* to talk about the *i*<sup>nd</sup> column or the *j*<sup>st</sup> row (I don't even know how you would pronounce those).

The same usage applies to *any* letter of the English alphabet - you can would talk about the *p*<sup>th</sup> prime number or the *k*<sup>th</sup> entry of the *n*<sup>th</sup> row of Pascal's triangle.

In all of these cases, you pronounce them by saying the name of the letter followed by "th", so that *i*<sup>th</sup> is /aɪθ/, *j*<sup>th</sup> is /dʒeɪθ/, *p*<sup>th</sup> is /piːθ/, etc.

Comment: Thanks @senshin ! I believe this will be very helpful to those whose native language is not English. :)

Comment: @bof I've heard both "_i_ plus oneth" and "_i_ plus first". I think both are acceptable. I would refer to the row indexed by $i^3$ as the "_i_ cubed row" with no ordinal marker, simply because "_i_ cubedth row" is a mouthful.